# Get Heading Number and Text from current selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for a function that returns the number and text of the currently last heading in a text, based on the current selection.

I want a function to return "1.1. Felines" from

```
1. Animals

Animals are sometimes domesticated.

1.1. Felines

Felines are *often* cats.

1.2. Canines

Canines are sometimes dogs.
```

where "often" ist my current selection. My current selection may (and will) be inside a table in my final application, so the function has to work inside tables, too.

The headings are the standard format templates "Heading 1" or "Heading 2"  or "Heading 3" that are present in every empty Word file.

The function should return the lowest level heading that is the last heading above the selection. Bonus points for a second function that returns the previous "level 1 Heading".

I have found this: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970614/get-heading-number-from-previous-heading) and other SO questions, but I am not deep enough into VBA to modify them to do what I want. I also googled into the *Selection.Information* and *Selection.Style* but hit a wall with both. For example *wdActiveEndSectionNumber* from *.Information* only returns the section number, but I do not use a new section for each heading. With the *.Style* I did not manage to find the last Heading before the selection.

Comment: This is asking others to do your work for you and is not what this site is about. Show what you have tried so far and make it a far more specific question.

Comment: I gave a reference to what kind of answers I found on SO and I stated what I found for possible functions with Google. I haven't gotten beyond one line of code yet because I couldn't get something to work with what I found, mostly just returned empty msgbox with the stray ? or heading number (when copy pasting a full code as in the link I gave).

Comment: I think the inbuilt feature of Microsoft Word is doing what you want. You use it like that: `Insert`->`Cross reference`->select `Header` and `Header text`, `Header number` respectively. Select the Header 2 in the overview below and hit `Insert`. That's it.